# DateTimPicker Validation (Yesterday)

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I would like to ask a question
So i have a datetimepicker 
So if i put the date from yesterday it will show a message that is "Invalid Date"

My aim is the date that should use is the only date today and the yesterday date cannot be use anymore

Comment: You saying you want to show a `datetimepicker` that only shows dates from today?

Comment: No. I mean is it will show "Invalid Date" if you put the date from yesterday so all you can use is the date today and not the date from yesterday

Comment: Are you asking how to make the program not process the date after it has shown "invalid date"?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Thank you bill for trying to help ! :D my question is already answered ! thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will accept only date today:

```
private void dt_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            String dtnow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            if (DateTime.Parse(dt.Text) < DateTime.Parse(dtnow))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date");
                //Return the date now
                dt.Text = DateTime.Parse(dtnow).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
}
```

Comment: Oh this Actualy works ! thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: Welcome.. i updated the answer above to return the date now.